# How to build generic table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to build generic table with structure like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lastname: Becker</td>
    <td>Firstname: Mirjam</td>
    <td>Compnany: bla</td>
    <td>Contry: Belgium</td>
    <td>
      <img height="49" width="37" src="style/user.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="userprofile.html">
        <img height="31" width="36" src="style/lupe.jpg" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have function but it does not work:

```
function createTableWithUserData() {
  cloud.getUsers("46daed956").then(function(userDetails) {
    var users = $('');
    $.each(steps.steps, function (i, s) {
      var element = $('<td>' + userDetails.lastName + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + userDetails.firstName + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + userDetails.Company + '</td>');
      users.append(element);
  });
}
```

Comment: What is generic about this table?

Comment: Your current code is creating neither the `<table>` nor the `<tr>` elements.

Comment: Where came the variable `steps` from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using a template:

```
<script id="userTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lastname: ${lastName}</td>
      <td>Firstname: ${firstName}</td>
      <td>Compnany: ${Company}</td>
      <td>Contry: ${Country}</td>
      <td>
        <img height="49" width="37" src="style/user.jpg" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="userprofile.html">
          <img height="31" width="36" src="style/lupe.jpg" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  cloud.getUsers("46daed956").then($.proxy($.tmpl))
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$('');` is not a table, use `$('<table>');` instead
2. You did not add the table to the document, its detached. Attach using `$('body').append(users);` after the loop.
3. Add a TR too.
4. Add another }.

Try this instead:

```
function createTableWithUserData() {
  cloud.getUsers("46daed956").then(function(userDetails) {
    var users = $('<table>');
    $.each(steps.steps, function (i, s) {
      var element = $('<tr><td>' + userDetails.lastName + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + userDetails.firstName + '</td>' +
                      '<td>' + userDetails.Company + '</td></tr>');
      users.append(element);
    }
    $('body').append(users);
  });
}
```

Comment: BTW: You better use js-render-templates.